# Почему функция подсчета байтов зависает при использовании более 4 байт?

Tags: javascript, переменные

Функция `size` возвращает количество байт, в которых хранится значение числовой переменной `disp`. Если значение `disp` помещается в 4 байтах, функция успешно выполняется. Однако, если значение занимает больше, чем 4 байта, функция почему-то зависает.

```
get size() {
  let bytes = 0;
  for (let t_disp = this.#disp; t_disp !== 0; bytes++) {
    t_disp >>= 0x08;
  }
  return bytes;
}
```

Почему функция подсчета байтов зависает при использовании более 4 байт? И как эту проблему решить?

Comment: Т.е. для числа 100000 вернёт три байта.. А для чего вам такая функция?

Comment: Битовые операции в JS работают только с 32-битными числами. Так что замените сдвиг на деление с округлением.

Comment: А зависает скорее всего из-за того что t_disp становится отрицательным, а сдвиг вправо сохраняет знак

Comment: @MBo , чтобы получать разрядность данных :)

Comment: @iEPCBM Мягко говоря, это неудачный вариант

Comment: В принципе размер можно получить, преобразовав число в строку с шестнадцатеричным представлением: `Math.ceil(this.#disp.toString(16).length/2);`. Но это не совсем красиво выглядит

Comment: Вы работаете со слабо  типизированным языком, и использование подобных низкоуровневых средств обычно свидетельствует о том, что неправильно выбран подход к задаче или инструмент (язык)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Количество байт, занимаемое числом, можно получить, преобразовав число в строку в шестнадцатеричным представлением. Тогда каждые 2 символа строки будут представлять 1 байт этого числа.

`Math.ceil(this.#disp.toString(16).length/2);`

Но в таком случае нулевое значение будет восприниматься как 1 байт. Чтобы такого избежать, можно добавить условие:

```
if (this.#disp !== 0) {
  return Math.ceil(this.#disp.toString(16).length/2);
}
return 0;
```